# continue entering tuples

Tags: haskell, io, syntax-error

I want the user to **enter** a list of tuples to search on it for a key like this can I say it like this

```
  data BookInfo = Book Int String [String]
  deriving(Show)
  findbook :: [BookInfo] -> Int -> BookInfo
  findbook vs key = (booker (vs!!(bookFinding vs  key 0 (length vs))) key)

  getBookInfo = do
    putStrLn "Enter book id :"
    k <- read
    putStrLn "Enter book name : "
    r <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter book subject :"
   m <- getLine 
   let Book book = enter k r [m] 
   return  book
 main = do
   putStr "Enter you first info is :"
   v <- getBookInfo
   let Book vs = v:[]
   c <- getLine
   if c == "N"
   then     
     putStr "You  done"   
   else
    Book booke = getBookInfo
    vs = booke:vs
  putStr "Do you want to search ? :" 
     m <- getch
      if m == 'y'
        then  
         putStr " Enter your key :"  
         s <- readNum  

 let Book w =  findBook vs s
 putStrLn" The result is: " ++ show(w)
```

But it gives me an error:

```
 The last statement in do must be m <- getch
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried fixing up your indentation?

Comment: For one thing, every `if` must have an `else` clause. Your final `if` doesn't have one.

Comment: Okay, I just spent a few minutes trying to fix up your code. My conclusion is that, at the moment, it's a complete mess. What are the functions `booker`, `bookFinding` and `enter`?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by indentation?

Comment: bookFinding :: [BookInfo] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
bookFinding vs key r w=(binsearch (combining vs) key r w)
booker :: BookInfo -> Int -> BookInfo
booker (Book id name subject) key |key==id = Book key name subject
                                  | otherwise =(Book 999 "nothing" ["nothing"] )   
findbook :: [BookInfo] -> Int -> BookInfo
findbook vs key = (booker (vs!!(bookFinding vs  key 0 (length vs))) key)                                                                 enter :: Int -> String -> [String] -> BookInfo
enter id name subject=Book id name subject

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to write a program to read a list of books into some sort of database, and then search the books. You start off well, with a data type that stores book info:

```
data BookInfo = Book Int String [String] deriving (Show)
```

Now let's look at your function which reads in book info from the user.

```
getBookInfo = do
    putStrLn "Enter book id :"
    k <- read
    putStrLn "Enter book name : "
    r <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter book subject :"
    m <- getLine 
    let Book book = enter k r [m] 
    return book
```

I fixed up your indentation for you (here's a tip: **use four spaces for indentation!**) but there are other problems:

- The line `k <- read` doesn't make any sense. The type of read is `read :: Read a => String -> a` but you're using it as if it was an I/O action. You need the function `readLn` instead.
- The line `let Book book = enter k r [m]` doesn't make any sense. It looks like you're used to writing in a language like C or Java, where you have to specify types. You don't have to do that in Haskell! Also, the `enter` function is unnecessary. You can just write `let book = Book k r [m]` and that will work fine. In fact, you don't need the temporary variable `book` at all - you can create the `Book` and return it all in one line.

So you can write:

```
getBookInfo :: IO BookInfo
getBookInfo = do
    putStrLn "Enter book id: "
    bookid <- readLn 
    putStrLn "Enter book name: "
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter book subject: "
    subject <- getLine 
    return (Book bookid name [subject])
```

which will now compile fine. Notice that I also added a type declaration (which is optional).

---

Your next function, `main`, is trying to do a bit too much. It contains all the rules for getting a list of books, and the rules for searching them. These are two separate tasks, so they should be in two separate functions. So let's write a function that gets a list of books:

```
getBookList :: IO [BookInfo]
getBookList = do
    putStr "Any more books? "
    answer <- getLine
    if answer == "N"
        then return []
        else do
            book  <- getBookInfo
            books <- getBookList
            return (book:books)
```

Take a while to understand how this function works. First it asks if you have any more books to enter. If you say "N" then it returns the empty list, and you're done. Otherwise, it does something magical - first, it calls `getBookInfo` to get the info for a single book. Then it calls *itself* to get a list of books! This is an example of recursion. Finally, it adds the first book to the list of books, and returns the whole list.

---

You should have a go at writing the rest of the program yourself now. I may revisit this answer in a day or so to add some more detail. I'm more likely to do that if you leave a comment letting me know what you're tried, and where you get stuck. Remember:

- Indent your code properly! Use four spaces. Get an editor like [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) that knows how to handle indentation.
- Try and write small (less then 10 lines) functions and chain them together to make a complete program. This will prevent you from losing your mind when trying to debug the 400 line monstrosity you've come up with.
- Check the types! You can load up ghci and type, for example, `:t read` to see the type of the `read` function.

Comment: You don't have to use four spaces for indentation; you just have to follow the offsides rule.

Comment: True, but when someone is using one space to indent, and half their problems come from incorrect indentation, I think it's helpful to tell them to use four spaces.

Comment: i write this function 
`searchBookList :: IO ()
searchBookList = do  
    putStr "Do you want to search ? "
    s <- getCh
    | s == "N" = [] 
    | otherwise = do
        putStrLn "Enter your list "
        let books = getBookList
        putStrLn"Enter your key"
        key <- read
        let search = findBook books key 
         return(search)`                                             for searcing but it give me an error that    `The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression:
    s <- getCh`